# Tensorflow graph construction Input type mismatch error

Tags: python, tensorflow

I got this error while trying to init the graph variables (by tf.global_variables_initializer()).

```
en/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1135, in _run
feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
File "/home/tunguyen/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1316, in _do_run
run_metadata)
File "/home/tunguyen/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1335, in _do_call
raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Input 1 of node while_2/Merge was passed float from while_2/NextIteration:0 incompatible with expected int32.
```

The graph is quite complex to put here. Here is a snippet of a while_loop that I suspect it might be where the error occurs.

```
  loop_cond = lambda a1, b1, idx_var: tf.less(idx_var, n_inodes)
  loop_vars = [inode_h, inode_c, idx_var]
  inode_h, inode_c, idx_var = tf.while_loop(loop_cond, _recurrence, loop_vars,
                                                  shape_invariants=[tf.TensorShape([None, self.hidden_dim]),
                                                                    tf.TensorShape([None, self.hidden_dim]),
                                                                    idx_var.get_shape()]
```

Comment: Can you post the code where you define the graph? Or at least the part that gives the error.

Comment: "The graph is quite complex to put here" if you need to say so, it means you need to try creating a minimal working example. While trying to do so, you'll likely find out the solution, or at least the culprit, yourself.

Comment: yes, I kind of need an interpreter of the error that is quite confusing to me.